# Create new column with values matching several conditions on other columns R Raster

Tags: r, merge, inner-join, raster

I have two raster maps. One represents land cover classes and the other biomass weight of the vegetation. And I want to create a new column "age".

Let´s assume that classes 2 and 3 represent trees. The other column give us the weight of the tree.

```
land_cover <- c('1','2','3','2','1','3')
weight <- as.numeric(c(50,60,70,80,70,90))
trees <- data.frame(land_cover, weight)

> trees
  land_cover weight
1          1     50
2          2     60
3          3     70
4          2     80
5          1     70
6          3     90
```

The new column will be assigned different values depending on whether its a tree (non-tree cells won´t be assigned any value), and its weight. I don´t know how to write the proper syntax in R.
It would be something like:

```
if (trees$land_cover 2 | trees$land cover 3) & (trees$weight < 80) then trees$age = 1
 if (trees$land_cover 2 | trees$land cover 3) & (trees$weight > 70 & trees$weight < 90) then trees$age = 3
```

Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: try `with(trees, ifelse(land_cover %in% 2:3 & weight < 80, 1, ifelse(land_cover %in% 2:3 & weight > 70 & weight < 90, 3, NA)))`

Comment: thanks, it works! i'm wondering, can I use 'ifelse' more than twice? Maybe I'm just getting in trouble with the parentesis and comas